# Using an array and JQUERY to build a "reactive" seleciton list. How do I pull data from the array based item selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm very new to JavaScript and JQUERY so please be gentle ;)

I have created an array that fills a second selection drop-down list based on the first selection: (thanks to Radical Fanatic for the code)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var productCategoryJsonList = {"productCategoryTable" :
        [
            {"productCategoryID" : "1","productCategory" : "Select a Product Category"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "2","productCategory" : "Pianos"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "3","productCategory" : "Organs"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "4","productCategory" : "Synthesizers"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "5","productCategory" : "Keyboards"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "6","productCategory" : "Guitar and Bass"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "7","productCategory" : "V-Drums"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "8","productCategory" : "Production"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "9","productCategory" : "Amplifiers"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "10","productCategory" : "AIRA"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "11","productCategory" : "Accessories"},
            {"productCategoryID" : "12","productCategory" : "HOSA Cables"}
        ]};
    var productModelJsonList = {"Pianos" :
        [
            {"productModelTypeID" : "1","productModel" : "V-Piano", "prodID" : "01010011A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "2","productModel" : "RG-3F", "prodID" : "03011070A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "3","productModel" : "LX-17", "prodID" : "03011050A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "4","productModel" : "LX-7", "prodID" : "03011050A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "5","productModel" : "HP603", "prodID" : "03011010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "6","productModel" : "HP605", "produD" : "03011010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "7","productModel" : "LX-15E", "prodID" : "03011050A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "8","productModel" : "HP508", "prodID" : "03011010A"}
        ],
        "Organs" :
        [
            {"productModelTypeID" : "1","productModel" : "V-Combo VR-09", "prodID" : "01010020A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "2","productModel" : "ATELLIER Combo AT-350C", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "3","productModel" : "AT-900 Platinum Edition", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "4","productModel" : "AT-900C", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "5","productModel" : "AT-800", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "6","productModel" : "AT-300", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "7","productModel" : "AT-100", "prodID" : "03021010A"},
            {"productModelTypeID" : "8","productModel" : "ATUP-EX", "prodID" : "03021011A"}
        ]
    };
console.log( "ready!" );

var CategoryListItems= "";
for (var i = 0; i < productCategoryJsonList.productCategoryTable.length; i++){
    CategoryListItems+= "<option value='" + productCategoryJsonList.productCategoryTable[i].productCategoryID + "'>" +
    productCategoryJsonList.productCategoryTable[i].productCategory + "</option>";
    }
    $("#categorySelectionBox").html(CategoryListItems);

var updateSelectModelBox = function(category) {
    console.log("updating with",category);
    var productListItems= "";
    for (var i = 0; i < productModelJsonList[category].length; i++){
        productListItems+= "<option value='" + productModelJsonList[category][i].productModelTypeID + "'>" +
        productModelJsonList[category][i].productModel + "</option>";
    }
    $("select#modelSelectionBox").html(productListItems);
}

$("select#categorySelectionBox").on('change',function(){
    var selectedCategory = $('#categorySelectionBox option:selected').text();
    updateSelectModelBox(selectedCategory);
});
```

And the HTML code snippet is this:

```
<label>Category</label>
        <select id="categorySelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">Category</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Select your Model</label>
        <select id="modelSelectionBox" class="stringInfoSpacing">
            <option  id="selectModelBox" value="-1" selected="selected">Select your Model</option>
        </select>
```

The JSFIDDLE page is here : https://jsfiddle.net/Junedax/9z2t1tr2/21/

What I need to do now is extract the prodID value from the array based on what the user selects in the "Select your Model" drop-down selection. This value will then be passed onto another part of the website to filter a list of stores that sell the selected product.

Any ideas? I've looked at JQUERY parse and onclick functions but haven't had much success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: instead of having the values as 1,2,3 etc why dont you have the value as the prodID ? This way, it s easy to extract the value on change.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed to have an index key as the first column which increments numerically for it all to work correctly. I can definitely move the prodID values to the first column of data. If I were to do so how would I extract that value on change? I do remember reading about that somewhere so I'll head down that road.

Comment: you dont need an index. value is for anything you want it to be. If you wan to keep it you can define whatever attr you want in addition. retrieve the value or the attr as you want